# Trigger not running

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I'm reacting a trigger to insert new row into table Reorder when there is update on the Quantity value in Inventory table. When the quantity is updated to 8, nothing happens on the Reorder table, nothing has been added. Can anyone point out what's wrong with my trigger?

```
CREATE TRIGGER reorder
         AFTER UPDATE OF Quantity
            ON Inventory
      FOR EACH ROW
          WHEN "NEW.Quantity" < 10
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Reorder VALUES (
                            NEW.ProductID,
                            100
                        );
END;
```

Inventory has column StoreID, ProductID and Quantity while Reorder has column ProductID and Quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"NEW.Quantity"` is a string.

Double quotes would be correct for quoting table or column names, but there is neither a table nor a column named `NEW.Quantity`.

If you really want quotes, use `"NEW"."Quantity"`, but here, you don't need them at all.